# Array modifier creates inner intersected surfaces in spheres. How to deal with it? Select interior faces doesn't work

Tags: modifiers, faces, topology, intersection

Array modifier creates inner intersected surfaces in spheres after apply. How to deal with it in a beautiful way? "Select interior faces" doesn't work.

[image: Spheres after array modifier]

[image: Inner intersected faces]

Answer (score 1):

After applying the array modifier, you can then select the intersecting spheres, go into edit mode, press 'A' to select all if not everything is selected, and then select Face -> Intersect (Boolean).

Set the Boolean Operation to 'Union', the solver to 'Exact', and be sure to have 'Self Intersection' enabled.

[image]

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you a lot!